# How can XSD require a child element in all or no members of a sequence?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-validation

Here's what I got:

```
<xs:element name="items">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="item">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="id"/>
      <xs:element ref="filename"/>
            <xs:element ref="file_url"/>
      <xs:element ref="metadata"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Now I want metadata to be optional, but the following should be invalid:

```
<items>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <filename>asd.dat</filename>
    <file_url>bla</file_url>
    <metadata>...</metadata>
  </item>
  <item>
    <id>1</id>
    <filename>asd.dat</filename>
    <file_url>bla</file_url>
    <!-- metadata missing -->
  </item>
</items>
```

So either it should be missing everywhere, or be present everywhere. 
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSD 1.0

You cannot directly represent your constraint in XML Schema 1.0.  You could use [Schematron](http://xml.ascc.net/resource/schematron/) or check it at the application level.  You could also rewrite your XSD to allow two types of items:  `item` which does not allow `metadata` and `item_meta` which requires it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        <xs:element ref="item_meta" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:group name="commonItemElements">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id"/>
      <xs:element name="filename"/>
      <xs:element name="file_url"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:group>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:group ref="commonItemElements"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="item_meta">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="commonItemElements"/>
        <xs:element name="metadata"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

### XSD 1.1

In XML Schema 1.1, you can [specify co-occurrence constraints](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-xml11pt2/) via XPath 2.0 using `xs:assert` to constrain the number of optional `metadata` elements to be 0 or equal to the number of `item` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="items">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:assert test="(count(item/metadata) = 0) or (count(item/metadata) = count(item))"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="id"/>
        <xs:element name="filename"/>
        <xs:element name="file_url"/>
        <xs:element name="metadata" minOccurs="0"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```